# OctoPack for deployment packaging all web.config files

Tags: asp.net, octopus-deploy

I am using OctoPack in my asp.net project to package for deployment to my environments. I noticed that OctoPack is packaging all the web.config transformation files in the package. How do I get it to transform into the one web.config so that they are not all sent to all environments?

Note: I would like to keep the default behavior of not setting up a nuspec file if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transformation is not done by OctoPack but by Octopus Deploy during the deployment.

I will assume you're using Octopus Deploy. If your Nuget package contains the transform files (like f.ex. Web.Release.config) then all you need to do is to goto your projects Process and the relevant step, click the Features link and enable Config transforms. You will have new options where you can also specify additional transforms you want to run.

More details under "Config transformations" here http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Configuration+files

Comment: If you have a custom Web.#{Environment}.config that you also want transformed against the base Web.config make sure you include it in the solution as either Content or "Copy to output folder" so that you can reference it under the custom transforms field in Octopus.

Comment: If I wanted to avoid adding these files to the project. `(They are stored somewhere else in our Version Control)`, I've added the folder into the Project.nuspec and it appears in the nuget zip. Is this possible?